# CMake 3.11 does not generate Visual Studio solution file (.sln)

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

CMake 3.9 creates a Visual Studio 2017 Solution (*.sln) file for my project which I can then open in the IDE to edit and build my project. CMake 3.11 for the same projects runs ok but does not generate a solution file. Has something changed in CMake's support for solution files? The CMake changelogs don't mention anything related.

This small project demonstrates the problem:

```
project(MyProject)
enable_language(CSharp)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME}
    SOURCES MyFile.cs # Missing MyProject.sln
#   SOURCES MyFile.txt # OK
)
```

With 3.9 both SOURCES lines produce a MyProject.sln. With 3.11, the line with MyFile.cs does not produce a MyProject.sln.

Comment: Please improve your question by making it https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. No indication of changes to Solution Files: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/search?o=desc&q=sln&s=committer-date&type=Commits (No changes since 3.9.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please give us more information. Did you re-generate from scratch? Did you compare the `CMakeCache.txt` from both versions? Does a simple "Hello World" project work? Does it work on another computer? What does `CMakeFiles\CMakeError.log` say? Because if the generator completes without an error there should be a build environment.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that there should be a solution file. The generator completes without error but the solution file is missing. It took me a while to isolate the problem in our large project but I have now added a minimal sample of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once, then I deleted all files and re-generate from scratch, it worked.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It neither describes actual steps to solve the problem nor does it describe the cause of the problem. The answer might as well have been restart your PC and try again.